# PHP form no error but no message arriving

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have the following problem, I have a php script to send a form but unfortunately it saying the mail got send but nothing ever arrives. Any ideas what the problem could be? Also nothing in the spam folders.

This is the form:

```
<?php

$to = "name@domain.com"; //This is the email address you want to send the email to
//$subject_prefix = ""; //Use this if you want to have a prefix before the subject

if(!isset($_GET['action'])) {
  die("You must not access this page directly!"); //Just to stop people from visiting contact.php normally
}

$subject = 'Contactform'; //The subject

/* Now lets trim up the input before sending it */
$name = trim($_GET['name']); //The senders name
$email1 = trim($_GET['email1']); //The senders email address
//$subject = trim($_GET['subject']); //The senders subject
$message .= "===================================="."\n";
$message .= "Kontaktanfrage"."\n";
$message .= "===================================="."\n\n";
$message .= "Name: ".$name."\n";
$message .= "email: ".trim($_GET['email1'])."\n";
$message .= "Telefon: ".trim($_GET['phone1'])."\n";
$message .= "Strasse: ".trim($_GET['street'])."\n";
$message .= "Stadt: ".trim($_GET['city'])."\n";
$message .= "------------------------------------"."\n\n";
$message .= "Nachricht: "."\n".trim($_GET['msg'])."\n\n"; //The senders message
$message .= "===================================="."\n";

if ( empty($name) or empty($_GET['phone1']) or empty($_GET['msg']) ) {
  echo 'errorarea|Bitte f&uuml;llen Sie folgende Felder aus: Name, Telefon und Nachricht!';

} else {
mail($to,$subject,$message,"From: ".$email1.""); //a very simple send
  echo 'contactarea|Vielen Dank '.$name.', Ihre eMail wurde verschickt.'; //now lets update the "contactarea" div on the contact.html page. The contactarea| tell's the javascript which div to update.
}
?>
```

and this is the script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function createRequestObject() {
            var ro;
            var browser = navigator.appName;
            if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
                ro = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }else{
                ro = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            return ro;
        }

        var http = createRequestObject();

        function sendemail() {
            var msg = document.contactform.msg.value;
            var name = document.contactform.name.value;
            var email1 = document.contactform.email1.value;
            var phone1 = document.contactform.phone1.value;
            var street = document.contactform.street.value;
            var city = document.contactform.city.value;
            //var subject = document.contactform.subject.value;
            document.contactform.send.disabled=true; 
            document.contactform.send.value='Absenden';

            http.open('get', '/js/message.php?msg='+msg+'&name='+name+'&email1='+email1+'&phone1='+phone1+'&street='+street+'&city='+city+'&action=send'); //'&subject='+subject+
            http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
            http.send(null);
        }

        function handleResponse() {
            if(http.readyState == 4){
                var response = http.responseText;
                var update = new Array();

                if(response.indexOf('|' != -1)) {
                    update = response.split('|');
                    document.getElementById(update[0]).innerHTML = update[1];
            document.contactform.send.disabled=false; 
            document.contactform.send.value='Absenden';
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
<div id="contact">
    <h3>Kontaktformular</h3>
    Bitte f&uuml;llen Sie alle unten aufgef&uuml;hrten Felder aus damit wir Ihre Kontaktanfrage bestm&ouml;glich bearbeiten k&ouml;nnen<br/>
    <br/>
    Vielen Dank.<br/>
    <br/>
    Um Ihre Anfrage richtig bearbeiten zu k&ouml;nnen bitten wir Sie alle Felder richtig auszuf&uuml;llen.<br/>
    <br/>
    <form name="contactform" id="contactform">
        <label for="name">Name *</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="24"><br/>

        <label for="street">Strasse</label>
        <input type="text" name="street" id="street" size="24"><br/>

        <label for="zip">PLZ/Stadt</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="24"><br/>

        <label for="phone1">Telefon *</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone1" id="phone1" size="24"><br/>

        <label for="email1">eMail</label>
        <input type="text" name="email1" id="email1" size="24"><br/>

        <div style="height: 10px;"></div>

        <label for="message">Nachricht *</label>
        <textarea name="msg" rows="5" id="msg" cols="25"></textarea>

        <hr noshade size="1px" color="#E0DFA5">

        <div style="color: #CFCDC3; font-size: 9px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;">* Diese Felder werden ben&ouml;tigt.</div>
        <div id="contactarea" style="text-align: center;"><div id="errorarea"></div></div>
        <input type="button" class="submit" value="Absenden" name="send" onclick="sendemail();" id="submitbutton">
    </form>
</div>
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: is the php script running on local test machine or live site?

Comment: On a live site at the moment

Comment: How is it really testing the mail is actually sent? It looks like you are printing the thank you message regardless. Do `if(mail()) // print message`, but put in your mail parameters of course.

Comment: there is an error in the javascript callback function - if(response.indexOf('|' != -1)) { should be if(response.indexOf('|') != -1) {

Comment: I'm not good at coding I copied from a finished script and made some changes. on a different server where I have that script it works fine. So not sure where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the live site allows the sending of emails

```
<?php
    /*
        Why not use POST to send the data via ajax?
        Then you could use 
        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        }
    */
    /* Comment out the lines below if you get a response in the console and receive an email */
    $res=mail('me@example.com','test','this is a test');
    echo $res;
    print_r( $_GET );
    exit();
    /* comment out above lines */

    if( !isset($_GET['action']) ) {
        die("You must not access this page directly!");
    }

    $to = "name@domain.com";
    $subject = 'Contactform';
    /*
        There is no filtering of the request - you could use
        filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'email1', FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED, array( 'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH ) );
        to provide some basic filtering of supplied data
    */
    $name = trim($_GET['name']);
    $email1 = trim($_GET['email1']);

    /*
        Initially you had $message.= but there was no message at that stage
    */
    $message = "===================================="."\n";
    $message .= "Kontaktanfrage"."\n";
    $message .= "===================================="."\n\n";
    $message .= "Name: ".$name."\n";
    $message .= "email: ".trim($_GET['email1'])."\n";
    $message .= "Telefon: ".trim($_GET['phone1'])."\n";
    $message .= "Strasse: ".trim($_GET['street'])."\n";
    $message .= "Stadt: ".trim($_GET['city'])."\n";
    $message .= "------------------------------------"."\n\n";
    $message .= "Nachricht: "."\n".trim($_GET['msg'])."\n\n";
    $message .= "===================================="."\n";

    if ( empty($name) or empty($_GET['phone1']) or empty($_GET['msg']) ) {
        echo 'errorarea|Bitte f&uuml;llen Sie folgende Felder aus: Name, Telefon und Nachricht!';
    } else {
        /* Test for return value of mail call and use to decide which message to send */
        $response=mail( $to, $subject, $message, "From: ".$email1 );
        if( $response==true ) echo 'contactarea|Vielen Dank '.$name.', Ihre eMail wurde verschickt.';
        else echo 'contactarea|Failed';
    }

?>


<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
    function sendemail() {
      var http = navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer" ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();
      var msg = document.contactform.msg.value;
      var name = document.contactform.name.value;
      var email1 = document.contactform.email1.value;
      var phone1 = document.contactform.phone1.value;
      var street = document.contactform.street.value;
      var city = document.contactform.city.value;

      document.contactform.send.disabled=true; 
      document.contactform.send.value='Absenden';

        /* Why use GET as the method here?? */
      http.open('GET', '/js/message.php?msg='+msg+'&name='+name+'&email1='+email1+'&phone1='+phone1+'&street='+street+'&city='+city+'&action=send');
      http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if( http.status==200 && http.readyState==4 ){

            console.log(http.responseText);

            var response = http.responseText;
            if( response.indexOf('|') != -1 ) {
                update = response.split('|');
                document.getElementById(update[0]).innerHTML = update[1];
                document.contactform.send.disabled=false;
                document.contactform.send.value='Absenden';
            }
        }
      };
      http.send(null);  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Ram Raider tried it but unfortunately the Send Button does not work anymore.
What I forgot to say is that the form gets called into a lightbox popup. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: I have just tried this code without the lightbox and that all seems ok. Does the lightbox inject a new div somewhere within the HTML ( I presume it does ) and if so where? Try putting an alert statement in the sendemail function to see if the click is registered and also look in the console to see if there are any error messages

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it actually only opens the page with the script and form in a fancybox:
`<a href="contactform.php" class="various fancybox.ajax"><img src="images/button_form.jpg" width="130" height="30" border="0" style="border: none;" /></a>`
Strange is that the form works fine on a other server, but on this server it just shows that its been sent and no one receives the mail.